# What is the intent the use of the expression "purely optional?"

Tags: meaning

Here is some context, this comes from an programming interview/coding exercise:

> If you desire you may also use the following libraries (although this is purely optional): 
>     ...

Is the intent of the author indicating "you really should use one of these libraries" or, since you didn't desire to, use none of them.

Comment: You may use the libraries if you want to, but you don't have to. It's your choice.

Comment: ***purely*** is an ***intensifier*** here (probably because author wants to emphasise that not only is it not *mandatory* to use those libraries - he's going out of his way to avoid any suggestion that *he personally* might have a  preference for whether you do or not, so ***don't ask him to make your choice for you***).

Answer (score 1):

In this usage, purely is being used as an intensifier. The speaker is making sure you do not interpret any underlying obligation in his or her mentioning of this additional thing. Adding the 'if you desire' makes the sentence even more laid-back and informal. You can feel free to make use of any (or all, or none) of the resources provided to complete your task, it's just a friendly offer of saving you time if it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

**purely** optional [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/154852?rskey=akdZB7&result=2#eid)

> c. Simply, merely; exclusively, solely; ‘and nothing else’.

No tricks ... use or do not use the libraries, with no prejudice.